# jQuery syntax issues

Tags: jquery, syntax

Sorry for this stupid question, but how can I add this line

```
$("#wrapper").css("display", "none")
```

to this piece of code?

```
        $(".displaymedia").fancybox({

            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }

        });
```

Dreamweaver is giving me syntax errors all the time...

Comment: please type errors which you are getting..

Comment: when do you want the `#wrapper` to be hidden?

Comment: if it's a permanent state, use inline styles or preferably CSS to fix this...

Comment: @kalley: After the link is clicked...

Comment: @Puzzled Boy: I pasted this `$("#wrapper").css("display", "none")` in the second (blank) line and Dreamweaver gave me a syntax error warning

Comment: Here is the whole code btw. http://pastebin.com/DqnF7q6J I need it somewhere at line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".displaymedia").fancybox({

        helpers: {
            title : {
                type : 'outside'
            },
            overlay : {
                speedOut : 0
            }
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            $("#wrapper").css("display", "none");
        }

    });
```

Make sure to check the [API](http://fancybox.net/api) documentation first.